# Trait as generic parameter to struct object intialization

Tags: rust, blockchain, traits, generic-programming, substrate

I have this struct:

```
use sp_runtime::traits::Block;

struct Bar<T: Block> {
    e1: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T: Block> Bar<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Bar { e1: Vec::new() }
    }
}
```

Where [`Block`](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/2.0.0/sp_runtime/traits/trait.Block.html) is from the `sp_runtime` crate.

In main:

```
fn main() {
    let var_1 = Bar::<Block>::new();
}
```

[Full Code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=124c24ca676c4b3b14c1705b3ad660d5)

This code throws compilation error that trait can't be made into an object. I'm new to Rust, much of online solution haven't addressed this issue. Kindly let me know how to get around initialization of bar object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion likely stems from the fact that the `sp_runtime` crate has two items called `Block`. One is the trait `sp_runtime::traits::Block` and the other is a struct, `sp_runtime::generic::Block`, which implements that trait.

Traits can be used as a *constraint* on a type parameter, but they cannot be used as a type argument.

So, in your definition of `Bar<T>`, you can constrain `T` with `sp_runtime::traits::Block`, but when you construct an instance of `Bar<T>`, `T` needs to be the struct instead.

```
use sp_runtime::traits::Block;

struct<T: Block> Bar {
    e1: Vec<T>,
} 
   
impl<T: Block> Bar<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Bar {
            e1: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
} 

fn main() {
    use sp_runtime::generic::Block;
    let var_1 = Bar::<Block>::new();
}
```

However, given that this is the *only* implementation of the trait in the crate, you can just avoid mentioning the trait altogether and use the concrete struct type (unless you plan on implementing it yourself or depending on implementations from other crates):

```
use sp_runtime::generic::Block;

struct Bar{
    e1 : Vec<Block>,
} 
   
impl Bar {
    pub fn new() -> Self{
        Bar {
            e1: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
} 

fn main() {
    let var_1 = Bar::new();
}
```